# how is the dom cached between functions in an object literal? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom, design-patterns

Ok I'm not sure the title of this post is the correct way to refer to what I mean and I'm pretty sure I already know the answer to this question but I just wanted some clarification.

If I have an oject like this

```
var myObj = {
  settings : {
    domObj = document.getElementById('elem1');
  },
  myFunc1 : function () {
    return this.domObj;
  },
  myFunc2 : function () {
    return this.domObj;
  }
}

myObj.myFunc1();
myObj.myFunc2();
```

Is the domObj cached the first time it is accessed or is the dom traversed in both functions? I am attempting to access the Dom only once but not sure if this is a possible solution.

Comment: Yes, by doing this, object is cached and traversed only once.

Comment: I think you need to learn the difference between objects and funtions. myFunc1 and myFunc2 in your example are not functions and will not "return" anything.

Comment: That code is syntactically incorrect.  Did you forget `function()` after the colons?

Comment: Doh! Yes I did forget to make myfunc1 and 2 functions. Its a consequence of trying to ask a question on my phone. Also forgot var for myobj, didn't intend to make it global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really meant this:

```
var myObj = {
  settings : function() {
    domObj = document.getElementById('elem1');
  },
  myFunc1 : function() {
    return this.domObj;
  },
  myFunc2 : function() {
    return this.domObj;
  }
};
```

the answer is that "domObj" is a global variable **because you forgot the `var` keyword.**  Now, you may have meant this:

```
var myObj = {
  domObj: null,
  settings : function() {
    this.domObj = document.getElementById('elem1');
  },
  myFunc1 : function() {
    return this.domObj;
  },
  myFunc2 : function() {
    return this.domObj;
  }
};
```

in which case "domObj" is just a property of "myObj". It'd get set if you call

```
myObj.settings();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your doing "this.domObj =" and the other corrections you've noted; yes; the DOM element is cached in this.domObj. The only time the DOM is actually traversed is when you're calling DOM traversal methods. Assigning a DOM element to a variable/object property works *exactly* the same as any other assignment.